# TeX live in cygwin fails to find babel-swedish

Tags: cygwin

I use cygwin on Windows 7. I use cygwin as I am not allowed to install something else and cygwin is used in my work. I found out that TeX live is there, in cygwin. I managed to set cygwin up for babel-swedish in the `language.dat` file, and it worked fine.

Last week I did a version update, of the cygwin installation. 
Now, Swedish isn't working anymore. `pdflatex` cannot find the same `language.dat` file as before. I tried to edit `language-local.dat` file in the `texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/`, but in vain! 
It seems not to find any of these files anymore.

Where do I now add Swedish for Babel?
'tlmgr info babel-swedish' tells me it is there but not installed.

Comment: Sorry, but this description lacks all details. OS of Laptop? Why cygwin (you can install texlive on most operating systems, on Windows e.g. without cygwin)) What did you update? Can you post a minimal working example and post the error message as well?

Comment: it is unlikley to be related to cygwin, what does `tlmgr info babel-swedish` say? is it installed?

Comment: @KeksDose I use cygwin texlive as my main tex installation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Otherwise things were too easy for you, obviously. But I'm glad to hear that: your case! :-)

Comment: @KeksDose, I have now updated my question with some more details. We are not local admins at my office.

Comment: @CajC David will be glad to hear it!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are some new details...

Comment: what does `tlmgr info babel-swedish` report in your updated setup?

Comment: $ tlmgr info babel-swedish
...
package:     babel-swedish
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Babel support for typesetting Swedish
longdesc:    The package provides the language definition file for Swedish.
installed:   No
sizes:       src: 29k, doc: 129k, run: 9k
relocatable: Yes
cat-version: 2.3d
cat-date:    2018-01-13 10:24:37 +0100
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  swedish multilingual-addon
collection:  collection-langeuropean

Comment: I think the key here is `Installed: No`. Try: `tlmgr install babel-swedish`

Comment: Also,I edited your post a bit, hopefully in a way that will make it more usefull. Feel free to rollback my changes if you don't like them

Comment: I tried this and get
$ tlmgr install babel-swedish
tlmgr: action not allowed in system mode on Cygwin: install
Now I tried with --usermode and it says 
tlmgr install: package already present: babel-swedish
Very weird